# differentiating dynamic RTP payloads using type 97

Tags: audio-streaming, rtp, speex

When receiving and parsing RTP audio, how do I differentiate between the various payload types that all use the same dynamic payload type in the RTP header?  For example, I've got both Speex and iLBC packets coming in and both specify payload type 97 in the RTP header.  How else can I tell them apart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Payload types **96-127** fall under dynamic payload types (see [RFC3551](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551#section-6)), which means that you'll need the SDP if you want more information about the media type.

Comment: Thank you.  While I have already known this to be true, I keep thinking there is a way to recognize and parse unsolicited RTP that may arrive on an open port.  I'm thinking, for example, of a multi-client peer-to-peer communications environment such as a PTT/walkie-talkie application.  This may be true for some of the static payload types, but I keep forgetting that for the dynamic types (types 96 and above) there must also exist an out-of-band signaling and negotiation that takes place to specify the meaning of the dynamic types in the given conversation.